# Can't set automatically TimeZone in TimePicker

Tags: jquery, datetime, timepicker

Using [TimePiker](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon) I want to set timezone:

```
$('#timeStart').timepicker({
                showTimezone: true,
                timeFormat: "hh:mm TT",
                timezoneList: 
              [
                { 'value': '-720', 'label': '(GMT-12:00) International Date Line West' },
                { 'value': '-660', 'label': '(GMT-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa' }
                   ....
                { 'value': '+840', 'label': '(GMT+14:00) Time in Samoa' }
              ]
        });
```

timepiker is initialized and zones is added in selector but selected value is the first from list is not detected
if I set manually  option timezone: '+840' it work

why timezone is not detect automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution,instead of

```
{ 'value': '-720', 'label': '(GMT-12:00) International Date Line West' }
```

Is need to use

```
{ value: -720, label: '(GMT-12:00) International Date Line West' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that time picker, but if you can manually select it, by using

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

You can probably make a workaround it.

```
diff = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

timediff = diff/-60;


currentTimezone = (timediff > 0)? "+" : "-";
currentTimezone = (Math.abs(timediff) >= 9)? currentTimezone + Math.abs(timediff): currentTimezone +"0"+ Math.abs(timediff);
currentTimezone += "00";
console.log(currentTimezone)
```

Comment: "You can probably make a workaround it" does not look like answer, it belongs to comments.

Comment: @IvanJovovic I'm updating my answer with some code that might do the trick. Just wanted to start providing some light as soon as possible.

Comment: for timezone '+0300' new Date().getTimezoneOffset(); return -180

Comment: Yeah, 180minutes, you just need to divide by -60 (minus 60) to get the real hour, and then add two zeros, or if you might be dealing with not full hour timezones, (they exist), yo might need to get the modulus (%) also